# mermaidjs gitgraph how to create tag on main

Tags: mermaid

I receive a syntax error when trying to create a tag on my main branch in the example below:

```
    gitGraph
       commit
       tag: "v1.0"
       branch dev
       branch update-MS1-reference
       commit
       checkout dev
       merge update-MS1-reference 
       tag: "v1.1rc00"
       checkout update-MS1-reference
       commit
       checkout dev
       merge update-MS1-reference 
       tag: "v1.1rc01"
       checkout main
       merge dev
       tag: "v1.1"
```

If i try it in mermaid.live, i get this error message:
Expecting 'GG', 'EOF', 'NL', 'acc_title', 'acc_descr', 'acc_descr_multiline_value', 'section', 'CHECKOUT', 'BRANCH', 'CHERRY_PICK', 'MERGE', 'COMMIT', 'open_directive', ';', got 'COMMIT_TAG'

Why can i not create tags on the main branch?
I see no errors if i remove the tags from main like this:

```
    gitGraph
       commit
       branch dev
       branch update-MS1-reference
       commit
       checkout dev
       merge update-MS1-reference 
       tag: "v1.1rc00"
       checkout update-MS1-reference
       commit
       checkout dev
       merge update-MS1-reference 
       tag: "v1.1rc01"
       checkout main
       merge dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to not be related to main at all, i was doing line breaks without spaces, so it would see "committag: "1.0".
After adding a space after commit on the line above, it worked